# Does this JavaScript / jQuery code leak in ie8 or other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-8

I spent a lot of time reading about memory leaks. I'm confused because what was true for ie6 is not true anymore for ie8 or newer browsers. From what I understand, this code could/would leak because, in a function, I created a DOM element on which I bind an event. Is my understanding correct? If so, would the code in comments would leak, too? If it does, what would be the best approach to not have a leak?

```
function somefunc() {
    var $CodeInstallation, $selInstallation;

    $CodeInstallation = jQuery(<...some form tag...>);

    $selInstallation = jQuery(
        '<input value="select"' +
        ' type="button" name="selInstallation" ' +
        ' id="idSelInstallation"/>')
        .appendTo($CodeInstallation.parent());

    // should I do that instead  ???
    /*
    jQuery('<input value="select"' +
       ' type="button" name="selInstallation" ' +
       ' id="idSelInstallation"/>')
       .appendTo($CodeInstallation.parent());
    $selInstallation = jQuery('#idSelInstallation');
    */

    $selInstallation.click( function() {
        alert('click!');
    }); // click
}
```

Comment: jQuery manages this issue; it does not *directly* attach your event handler to the DOM.

Comment: And, when the element is removed using a jQuery method, the events/data are properly removed by jquery, avoiding memory leaks. Of course, if you kept a reference to that element, it'l stay in memory until that referenced is removed. In your above code, you have no such reference.

Comment: @Kevin B Thanks but if I do not do a .remove() when the user surf away, would this create a browser memory leak ?

Comment: I've never encountered that issue or heard of that being an issue, but i don't know. Do you have a memory issue that you are trying to solve? Or are you just trying to prevent one from occurring. It would be easier if you simply test for a memory leak first, before trying to fix one that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pointy and Kevin B. The answer is no, due to the way jQuery handle events instead of attaching to the DOM objects.